# C# Oracle ODP.net periodic querying causes ORA-00604

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I need to execute the same query every second in `GetStuff` function, but after a minute or two Oracle throws ORA-00604 and runs out of cursors, I guess I need somehow to close open cursor after I return result. However I don't like the idea of re-connecting every time I need to query, my code is below:

```
public MyStuff GetStuff(string paramValue)
{
    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select XXX from YY where param = ? ";
    command.Parameters.Add(":param ", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = paramValue;
    IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       ...
    }
    command.Dispose();
    return stuff;
 }
```

Comment: *same query every second*, what would happen if it takes more than a second for it to execute, i think this might cause problems, can you not cache the results and increase the poll interval ?

Comment: Was that good answer? Could you react? Upvote, explain why not?

Answer (score 0):

reader also needs to be disposed:

```
public MyStuff GetStuff(string paramValue)
{
    using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "select XXX from YY where param = ? ";
        command.Parameters.Add(":param ", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = paramValue;
        using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            ...
            }
        }
        return stuff;
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is highly advised way to interact with IDisposables.